# Conversion of ISO date format, from string to date,gives error?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I have been trying to convert ISO date format ('2016-06-23T20:04:41.914Z') ,which is in string to date datatype .In Pig Docs,there is function ToDate which convert string into Date([this](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#datetime-functions)).
So i tried it in different ways:

1.

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE ToDate(status_date,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS);
```

Error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-06-23T20:04:41.914Z" is malformed at "T20:04:41.914Z"

2.

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE ToDate(status_date);
```

Error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: ""

3.

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE ToDate(status_date,'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ');
```

Error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: T

Please let me know if i am missing something or is there any other way other than writing udf and using concat.
Also let me know if any additional information is required.

Comment: The second method should work, I tried it in my environment its working correctly.     Can you show the output of the Dump of the status_date column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method should work, your data have some record have field status_date is null?